# Git - Rebasing two branches against master

Tags: git

I have three branches: master, branchA, and branchB. branchB is branched off of branchA and will eventually be merged onto branchA.

```
                                    K---L---M---N---O branchB
                                   /
              E---F---G---H---I---J  branchA
             /
A---B---C---D  master
```

I needed to get changes from master on both branches, so I ran the following

```
branch-a> git fetch origin master
branch-a> git rebase -i origin/master
branch-a> git push -f
```

This correctly rebased branchA against master, but I'm having trouble with branchB. Trying to rebase it onto branchA (which now has changes from master) isn't working as I hoped. I got a huge amount of merge conflicts when there should be 0 so I aborted the rebase. At a bit of a loss.

When I look at my PR for branchB (whose base branch is A), it now shows the commit history for branchA AND B when it should just be B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
git rebase --onto=branchA branchB~3 branchB
```

You could have done the whole thing in a kind-of single shot like this:

```
git checkout branchB
git rebase master
git branch -f branchA branchb~3
```

Comment: Should that '3' be the actual number of commits in branchB?

Comment: Edited post to reflect actual # of commits and clarified the commit history.

Comment: @SamPinheiro `branchB~3` meant `G` in your diagram until you vitiated the answer by changing the diagram.

Comment: I don't want to break anything, so I just need a precise answer. The previous example had branchA and B with the same number of commits so I want to make sure the number is right (as well as where I need to run the command)

Comment: Now it's `branchB~5`

Comment: And yes.... the number of commits past the original position of branchA